# JS function does not using given parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have php code, which generates html with onclick function. Actually this is list of products. Some products may have colors. And my code creates dropdown menu for color choose. For color choose I made onclick javascript function with parameters, product_id and choosen color. I want to get choosen color and put it instead product picture. But it takes only parameters for first generated product
My code:

```
<?php
                    $query="select * from v_products";
        try{
            $stmt = $dbh->query($query);
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);              
        }catch (PDOException $pe) {
            die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
        }
    while ($r = $stmt->fetch()):
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['photo_url']);?>" alt="" width="800" height="500" id=<?php echo "img".$r['product_id']; ?>>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p style="background-color:#FFD700;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['product_name']);?></p>
                    <p>Артикуль:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['product_articul']);?></p>
                    <p>Количество:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['quantity']);?></p>
                    <p style="font-size:large;" color=red>Цена:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['price']);?>&#8364;</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id=myBtn>Buy Now!</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a>
                    </p>
                    <?php
                    if($r['number_of_colours']!=0){

                        $q_palitra="select * from colors where product_id='".$r['product_id']."'";
                        try{
                        $stmt1 = $dbh->query($q_palitra);
                        $stmt1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);             
                        }catch (PDOException $pe1) {
                            die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe1->getMessage());
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div id="image-dropdown" >
                        <?php
                        $i=1;
                        while ($p = $stmt1->fetch()):
                        ?>
                            <input type="radio" id=<?php echo "line".$i; ?> name="line-style" value=<?php echo $i; ?>  onclick="<?php echo "lalalalala('".$r['product_id']."','".$p['color_url']."');";?>" /><label for=<?php echo "line".$i; ?> style="<?php echo "background:url('".$p['color_url']."') 50% 50%;"; ?>"></label>
                        <?php
                        $i++;
                        endwhile;
                        ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    <?php 
    endwhile;
    }
    ?>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../images/products/batman_ink_by_zombies_616-d5ljte8.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="500" id=img1>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p style="background-color:#FFD700;">Крем-мусс</p>
                    <p>Артикуль:223201</p>
                    <p>Количество:5</p>
                    <p style="font-size:large;" color=red>Цена:6&#8364;</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id=myBtn>Buy Now!</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a>
                    </p>
                                        </div>

            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../images/products/batwing_somewhat_3d_by_qbatmanp.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="500" id=img2>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p style="background-color:#FFD700;">Test</p>
                    <p>Артикуль:bla bla bla</p>
                    <p>Количество:2</p>
                    <p style="font-size:large;" color=red>Цена:152&#8364;</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id=myBtn>Buy Now!</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a>
                    </p>
                                        </div>

            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../images/products/aa.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="500" id=img7>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p style="background-color:#FFD700;">Test</p>
                    <p>Артикуль:2225xx</p>
                    <p>Количество:14 4</p>
                    <p style="font-size:large;" color=red>Цена:114&#8364;</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id=myBtn>Buy Now!</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a>
                    </p>
                                                <div id="image-dropdown" >
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line1 name="line-style" value=1  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Access 2007.lnk');" /><label for=line1 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Access 2007.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line2 name="line-style" value=2  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Excel 2007.lnk');" /><label for=line2 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Excel 2007.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line3 name="line-style" value=3  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Groove 2007.lnk');" /><label for=line3 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Groove 2007.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line4 name="line-style" value=4  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office InfoPath 2007.lnk');" /><label for=line4 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office InfoPath 2007.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line5 name="line-style" value=5  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office OneNote 2007.lnk');" /><label for=line5 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office OneNote 2007.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line6 name="line-style" value=6  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Outlook 2007.lnk');" /><label for=line6 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Outlook 2007.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line7 name="line-style" value=7  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007.lnk');" /><label for=line7 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line8 name="line-style" value=8  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Publisher 2007.lnk');" /><label for=line8 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Publisher 2007.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line9 name="line-style" value=9  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Word 2007.lnk');" /><label for=line9 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Word 2007.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line10 name="line-style" value=10  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Digital Certificate for VBA Projects.lnk');" /><label for=line10 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Digital Certificate for VBA Projects.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line11 name="line-style" value=11  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Clip Organizer.lnk');" /><label for=line11 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Clip Organizer.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line12 name="line-style" value=12  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office 2007 Language Settings.lnk');" /><label for=line12 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office 2007 Language Settings.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line13 name="line-style" value=13  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Diagnostics.lnk');" /><label for=line13 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Diagnostics.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line14 name="line-style" value=14  onclick="lalalalala('7','../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Picture Manager.lnk');" /><label for=line14 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Test/Microsoft Office Picture Manager.lnk') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../images/products/MasterCard-Debit.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="500" id=img8>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p style="background-color:#FFD700;">Новое</p>
                    <p>Артикуль:15xx1592</p>
                    <p>Количество:10 3</p>
                    <p style="font-size:large;" color=red>Цена:12003&#8364;</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id=myBtn>Buy Now!</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a>
                    </p>
                                                <div id="image-dropdown" >
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line1 name="line-style" value=1  onclick="lalalalala('8','../images/palitra/Новое/11.PNG');" /><label for=line1 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Новое/11.PNG') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line2 name="line-style" value=2  onclick="lalalalala('8','../images/palitra/Новое/2.PNG');" /><label for=line2 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Новое/2.PNG') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line3 name="line-style" value=3  onclick="lalalalala('8','../images/palitra/Новое/3.PNG');" /><label for=line3 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Новое/3.PNG') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                        <input type="radio" id=line4 name="line-style" value=4  onclick="lalalalala('8','../images/palitra/Новое/4.PNG');" /><label for=line4 style="background:url('../images/palitra/Новое/4.PNG') 50% 50%;"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

For javascript it gets only first product id and first color of first product
How to get appropriate parameters for my javascript code.

```
function lalalalala(o, b){
 /*if(o.id=='line6'){*/
 //$("#img"+o).attr('src',b);
/*}else
$("#ccc").attr('src',array[0]);
*/
 //document.getElementById("'img'+o").src=b+"";
alert(b);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that on whichever radio you click, only color for first radio is being alerted?

Comment: @jaibatrik Yes, I tried to alert what came to javascript function. It shows first product id and url of first color of first object.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the function return value in the onclick event. Because you want to assign different parameters for different fields, I'd suggest changing the function:

```
function lalalalala(o, b) {

    return function() {
        // what you want to happen onclick goes here
        alert(b);
    }

}
```

That way, you're actually assigning a function to the onclick event: The function returned by `lalalalalala()`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your HTML and the JS function on jsbin.com

It worked perfectly fine. Have a look here -

http://jsbin.com/setezijabu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yeah. I have seen this page, but in fact it is still retrieving first product id and first product colors.

Comment: Do you have a link to your page, then I can try inspecting.

Comment: I can send to ur email. .zip of my localhost site and dump of my database

Comment: Just `save as` your HTML when it is rendered in your browser and upload it somewhere like Google Drive. You might need to zip it.

Comment: Please go by link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2BOpoKgUUSUEk5MWp2emM0aDQ/view?usp=sharing @jaibatrik